# Spring batch job repository tables are not getting created in the schema I configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am getting a similar problem. I have 2 datasources the primary and a second which should be used by spring batch. spring batch is creating the schema in the primary data source and trying to insert/update in the second here is my code:

The excetion: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE in statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]

```
public class DataSourceConfig {
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean("secondDataSourceProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.second-datasource")
public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

/**
 * Create primary (default) DataSource.
 */
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource primaryDataSource(@Autowired DataSourceProperties props) {
    return props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

/**
 * Create second DataSource and named "secondDatasource".
 */
@Bean("secondDatasource")
public DataSource secondDataSource(@Autowired 
@Qualifier("secondDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties props) {
    return props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
}
```

And

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class MyBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

/**
 * Initialize the BatchConfigurer to use the datasource of your choosing
 *
 * @param secondDatasource
 */

@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondDatasource")
DataSource datasource;

@Override
protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(datasource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
}

private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Error message does not look ambiguous to me. Did you check User privileges and existence of table already?

Comment: yes I did. the tables were not created

Comment: `spring batch is creating the schema in the primary data source` This is not correct. Spring Batch does not create tables. It is probably Spring Boot. So make sure to use the same datasource initialized by spring Boot in your Spring Batch configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did to make it work
I just added a bean in which the second data source is injected.

```
@Bean
BatchConfigurer configurer(@Autowired @Qualifier("secondDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
}
```

but still the schema was not created 
and I used :

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"dev","prod"})
public class JobRepositorySchemaConfig {
private final String JOB_REPO_SCHEMA = "classpath:batch_repo_schema.sql";

@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondDatasource")
DataSource datasource;

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@PostConstruct
public void loadIfInMemory() throws Exception {
    Resource resource = webApplicationContext.getResource("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql");
    Resource resource2 = webApplicationContext.getResource("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql");
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(datasource.getConnection(), resource);
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(datasource.getConnection(), resource2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create custom implementation of `BatchConfigurer`.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.MapJobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Component
public class MyBatchConfigurer implements BatchConfigurer {


    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondDatasource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        return jobRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    }

    @Override
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        return jobExplorer;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            this.jobRepository = createJobRepository();
            this.jobExplorer = createJobExplorer();
            this.jobLauncher = createJobLauncher();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
    }

    protected JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(datasource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    protected JobExplorer createJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```